# Estimating Algorithmic Information Content With EDA

Tags: information-theory, exploratory-data-analysis

I've compiled over 6000 county-level measures from the US Census into a `tsv` file and need a *high end* estimate of its algorithmic information content.  By "high end" I mean it should be *apparent* to skilled statisticians that compressing the file to that number of bits, including the decompression program's length, is feasible.  By "apparent" I mean it should not take much effort to have confidence in the feasibility of writing the de/compression program in, say, "R".  By "much effort" I mean that a number of skilled statisticians might find competing to achieve that level of compression, perhaps backed by [a prize](https://github.com/jabowery/SocialCausalityPrizeRound1), an intriguing challenge.

Clearly, exploratory data analysis techniques come into play in first-order estimates like this -- fully recognizing that the resulting first-order models will not be reliable.

How might one apply exploratory data analysis to come up with such an estimate?

What is a better way of estimating the algorithmic information content than this:

Not being a skilled statistician, I thought Principal Component Analysis might be useful in generating a first-order model of the data, the length of said model in "R" code being added to the length of the residual errors in bits, would provide such an estimate.  So I ran this "R" code:

```
lotc <- read.csv("https://github.com/jabowery/SocialCausalityPrizeRound1/raw/master/LaboratoryOfTheCounties.tsv", sep = "\t")
df<-lotc[-c(1)]
library(auto.pca)
auto.pca(df)
```

The idea being that if one were to write an "R" program that reproduced the original data from the principal components together with residual errors, the length of that program + the length of the stored principal components + the length of the residual errors, would be an estimate of the algorithmic information content.

The output of the above program is (forgive the length of what follows):

```
[1] "Number of Factors identified based on eigen Value greater than 1 : 75 Factors"
The determinant of the smoothed correlation was zero.
This means the objective function is not defined.
Chi square is based upon observed residuals.
The determinant of the smoothed correlation was zero.
This means the objective function is not defined for the null model either.
The Chi square is thus based upon observed correlations.
In factor.stats, the correlation matrix is singular, an approximation is used
Principal Components Analysis
Call: principal(r = input_data, nfactors = nfactors, rotate = "varimax", 
    scores = T)
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
             RC1   RC2   RC3  RC21   RC5   RC7  RC11  RC58  RC20   RC8   RC4
AFN110197D  1.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110202D  1.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110207D  1.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120197D  1.00  0.02  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120202D  1.00  0.02  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120207D  1.00  0.02  0.00  0.01  0.01  0.01 -0.01  0.02  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130197D  1.00  0.02  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130202D  1.00  0.02  0.00  0.01  0.01  0.01 -0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130207D  1.00  0.02  0.00  0.01  0.01  0.01 -0.01  0.02  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140197D  1.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.02  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140202D  1.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.02  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140207D  1.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.02  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
            RC27  RC17   RC9  RC10  RC12   RC6  RC23  RC15  RC32  RC30  RC18
AFN110197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01
AFN110202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120197D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01
AFN120202D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01
AFN120207D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01
AFN130197D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01
AFN130202D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01
AFN130207D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01
AFN140197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
            RC22  RC25  RC14  RC57  RC60  RC28  RC47  RC26  RC33  RC46  RC36
AFN110197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120197D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120202D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120207D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00
AFN130197D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130202D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130207D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00
AFN140197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00
AFN140202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00
AFN140207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00
            RC41  RC29  RC34  RC35  RC50  RC37  RC31  RC59  RC74  RC44  RC13
AFN110197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120197D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120202D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120207D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130197D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130202D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130207D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01
AFN140197D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140202D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140207D  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
            RC38  RC53  RC52  RC24  RC43  RC16  RC51  RC45  RC48  RC62  RC72
AFN110197D  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01
AFN110202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01
AFN110207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01
AFN120197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.02
AFN120202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.02
AFN120207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.02
AFN130197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.02
AFN130202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.02
AFN130207D  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.02
AFN140197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01
AFN140202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01
AFN140207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01
            RC19  RC49  RC39  RC54  RC55  RC42  RC40  RC61  RC64  RC67  RC56
AFN110197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN110207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN120207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01 -0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00
AFN130202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN130207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
AFN140207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
            RC63  RC66  RC65  RC75  RC73  RC69  RC71  RC68  RC70   h2
AFN110197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN110202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN110207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN120197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN120202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN120207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN130197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN130202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN130207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN140197D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN140202D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
AFN140207D  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00
                u2  com
AFN110197D 1.0e-04  1.0
AFN110202D 9.0e-05  1.0
AFN110207D 8.1e-05  1.0
AFN120197D 1.9e-03  1.0
AFN120202D 1.9e-03  1.0
AFN120207D 2.1e-03  1.0
AFN130197D 2.2e-03  1.0
AFN130202D 2.2e-03  1.0
AFN130207D 2.4e-03  1.0
AFN140197D 4.9e-04  1.0
AFN140202D 5.4e-04  1.0
AFN140207D 5.5e-04  1.0
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 6611 rows ]

                          RC1    RC2   RC3  RC21   RC5   RC7  RC11  RC58
SS loadings           5868.98 115.26 47.46 44.38 27.37 26.41 26.37 22.06
Proportion Var           0.89   0.02  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
Cumulative Var           0.89   0.90  0.91  0.92  0.92  0.93  0.93  0.93
Proportion Explained     0.90   0.02  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
Cumulative Proportion    0.90   0.91  0.92  0.93  0.93  0.94  0.94  0.94
                       RC20   RC8   RC4  RC27  RC17   RC9  RC10  RC12   RC6
SS loadings           21.68 17.02 16.94 16.36 16.21 15.90 15.21 14.98 14.41
Proportion Var         0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
Cumulative Var         0.94  0.94  0.94  0.94  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.96
Proportion Explained   0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
Cumulative Proportion  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.96  0.96  0.96  0.96  0.96  0.97
                       RC23  RC15  RC32  RC30 RC18 RC22 RC25 RC14 RC57 RC60
SS loadings           13.74 13.65 10.59 10.40 9.09 7.90 7.49 7.14 6.60 6.32
Proportion Var         0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Var         0.96  0.96  0.96  0.96 0.96 0.97 0.97 0.97 0.97 0.97
Proportion Explained   0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Proportion  0.97  0.97  0.97  0.97 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98
                      RC28 RC47 RC26 RC33 RC46 RC36 RC41 RC29 RC34 RC35 RC50
SS loadings           5.90 5.71 5.48 5.13 4.36 4.15 4.14 4.01 3.64 3.40 3.18
Proportion Var        0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Var        0.97 0.97 0.97 0.97 0.97 0.97 0.97 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98
Proportion Explained  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Proportion 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99
                      RC37 RC31 RC59 RC74 RC44 RC13 RC38 RC53 RC52 RC24 RC43
SS loadings           3.09 3.08 2.85 2.84 2.83 2.77 2.75 2.55 2.47 2.23 2.22
Proportion Var        0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Var        0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98
Proportion Explained  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Proportion 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99
                      RC16 RC51 RC45 RC48 RC62 RC72 RC19 RC49 RC39 RC54 RC55
SS loadings           2.20 2.12 2.10 2.04 2.02 1.97 1.95 1.94 1.90 1.89 1.81
Proportion Var        0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Var        0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98 0.98
Proportion Explained  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Proportion 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
                      RC42 RC40 RC61 RC64 RC67 RC56 RC63 RC66 RC65 RC75 RC73
SS loadings           1.79 1.77 1.75 1.68 1.59 1.48 1.34 1.28 1.23 1.23 1.22
Proportion Var        0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Var        0.98 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99
Proportion Explained  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Proportion 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
                      RC69 RC71 RC68 RC70
SS loadings           1.22 1.17 1.16 1.12
Proportion Var        0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Var        0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99
Proportion Explained  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Cumulative Proportion 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00

Mean item complexity =  1.2
Test of the hypothesis that 75 components are sufficient.

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0 
 with the empirical chi square  68724.2  with prob <  1 

Fit based upon off diagonal values = 1
 ################################################################
 #############  Uncorrelated Variables Identified  ##############
 ################################################################

 [1] "AFN110197D" "AFN120197D" "AFN120207D" "AFN130197D" "AFN130202D"
 [6] "AFN140197D" "AFN140207D" "AFN210197D" "AFN210202D" "AFN220197D"
[11] "AFN220207D" "AFN230197D" "AFN230202D" "AFN240202D" "AFN310202D"
[16] "AFN310207D" "AFN320197D" "AFN330197D" "AFN340197D" "AGE010180D"
[21] "AGE040200D" "AGE040204D" "AGE040206D" "AGE050200D" "AGE130201D"
[26] "AGE130205D" "AGE130208D" "AGE135202D" "AGE135207D" "AGE160200D"
[31] "AGE160203D" "AGE230203D" "AGE230205D" "AGE260200D" "AGE290203D"
[36] "AGE290206D" "AGE310180D" "AGE340207D" "AGE370201D" "AGE410200D"
[41] "AGE460202D" "AGE530201D" "AGE530204D" "AGE560206D" "AGE560209D"
[46] "AGE610200D" "AGE660207D" "AGE670190D" "AGE730209D" "AGE770202D"
[51] "AGE775204D" "AGE850200D" "AGE870209D" "AGN030207D" "AGN270197D"
[56] "AGN400197D" "AGN510202D" "AGN740197D" "AGN750197D" "AGN755197D"
[61] "AGS310192D" "ANC020200D" "ANC060190D" "ANC225209D" "ANC775209D"
[66] "ANC780190D" "ANC780200D" "ANC785200D" "ANC785209D" "ANC800200D"
[71] "WTN270207D"
Warning messages:
1: In cor.smooth(r) : Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done
2: In fa.stats(r = r, f = f, phi = phi, n.obs = n.obs, np.obs = np.obs,  :
  In factor.stats, the correlation matrix is singular, and we could not calculate the beta weights for factor score estimates
3: In principal(input_data, nfactors = nfactors, rotate = "varimax",  :
  The matrix is not positive semi-definite, scores found from Structure loadings
```

75 factors with eigen value greater than 1 is a **lot** lower than 6000, but then there is the information content of the error, which will be large but presumably not as large as the original data in bits.  Estimating the bits in the PCA model should be straight forward, but then how can one estimate the number of bits required by the residual error?

Comment: By using PCA you seem implicitly suggesting that the decompressed file may be allowed to differ by some nonzero amount from the original file.  If that's the case, how will you measure the size of the difference?  If it's not the case, why should PCA have anything to offer unless--apparently by some accident of the data--some of its eigenvalues are exactly zero?

Comment: The decompressed file would not be allowed to differ.  The errors would have to be stored along with the PCA parameters.  I've edited to clarify this.

Comment: Any degree of prediction will reduce the number of bits required to losslessly compress the data.  If PCA parameters have any predictive value, they will reduce that number.

Comment: The only sense in which PCA could have "predictive value" is when one or more eigenvalues are zero.  At the same time, you pay the price of having to store the eigenvectors.  Thus, employing PCA very well could cost you extra bits rather than saving any.

Comment: Very well, I've further-edited to discount my uninformed approach and focus the question.